# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 3x3 matrix A with all rows being the same i.e. [a, b, c]

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues and vectors of the matrix A = [[a b c], [a b c], [a b c]]. I tried to find the characteristic polynomial and got -x^3 + x^2(a+b+c) + x(ab - bc) = 0 but I'm stuck now as I don't know how to find the roots of the equation. I feel like I'm missing something as this is just an ordinary example in my text book and all the rows being the same there should be some trick I don't get, I think.

Comment: Try finding some eigenvectors. One should be fairly obvious.

Comment: It should be $-x^2(x-a-b-c)$

Comment: Your characteristic polynomial is erroneous: it should be of the form $Ax^3+Bx^2$ (with a factorization of $x^2$ which means that $0$ is a double root).